# Check n-words frequency for the open ended questions

Tags: r, text-mining, tm

I want to analyze answers from open ended questions. Single Word Cloud first, and then I met a problem when I want to count the frequency of  2-3 words phrase.

Here is my codes:

```
library('tm')
tokenize_ngrams <- function(x,n=2)return(rownames(as.data.frame(unclass(textcnt(x,method="string",n=n)))))
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(texts))
matrix <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus,control=list(tokenize=tokenize_ngrams))
inspect(matrix[1:4, 1:3])
```

The results should be the 2-word phrases and the frequency.
But I got the results as follows:

```
                 Docs
Terms            1 2 3
document         1 0 0
first            1 0 0
the              1 1 1
this             1 1 1
```

[image: Results of this code]

Answer (score 0):

Don't know the answer using **tm**, but this will work fine:

```
require(quanteda)
matrix <- dfm(texts, ngrams = 2)
head(matrix)
```